# Geometric interpretation of $ \frac{x^2+y^2}{y}=\text{constant} $.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometric-interpretation

I would love help in interpreting the following expression geometrically

$$ \frac{x^2+y^2}{y}=\text{constant} $$

for simplicity, let $ c = \text{constant} $, and then through rearrangement we have

$$ x^2+y^2=cy $$

where it is evident that

$$ cy = r^2 $$

where r represents radius

Conceptually, I've broken the problem down into the radius being a function of y, but I am having trouble moving forward from this point. How should I proceed?

Comment: Try [graphing the function with different values of $c$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) to gain an intuition about it.

Comment: @Matt isn't the radius c/2?

Comment: @Moti yes, that's why I deleted my comment. Give me a break, I was doing it in my head! :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to:

$$x^2+(y-c/2)^2=c^2/4, \ \ y\neq 0.$$

Does this look familiar? One thing to keep in mind is your original equation does not allow for $y=0$, so this carries over to the above equation, a circle missing points on the $x$ axis.

Comment: Looks very familiar - thanks!

Comment: I might just add to your solution that y=0 is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$x^2+y^2=cy\iff x^2+(y-c/2)^2=c^2/4.$$ So, the solution is a circumference, without the points where $y=0.$ If $c\le 0$ you can only consider $y\ne 0$, because we can't divide by zero.

Comment: Sure, it's an ellipse, but it's also a circle, and there is a solution when $c<0$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thank you for noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have the following equation, as you did:
$$x^2+y^2=cy$$

Subtract both sides by $cy$:
$$x^2+y^2-cy=0$$

We want to complete the square with $y^2-cy$. To do this, add both sides by $\left(\frac c 2\right)^2$.
$$x^2+y^2-cy+\left(\frac c 2\right)^2=\left(\frac c 2\right)^2$$

$y^2-cy+\left(\frac c 2\right)^2=\left(y-\frac c 2\right)^2$, so substitute on the left side:

$$x^2+\left(y-\frac c 2\right)^2=\left(\frac c 2\right)^2$$

Thus, this is simply a circle centered at $\left(0, \frac c 2\right)$ with radius $\frac c 2$.